# For fun: coding wave function / sinosoidal surfaces for friend's birthday T-shirt

Tags: r, plot, waveform, graphical-programming

This post is to hopefully bring some joy to an awesome fella. He used to have a favourite T-shirt (pictured) which had 6 graphical functions on it. Eventually, the T-shirt fell apart about 10 years ago.

I wanted to surprise him for his birthday and replace the T-shirt as far as possible. As it isn't available to buy (or even anything similar) any more, I wanted to try and code up 6 such images, so I could combine them and get them printed onto a T-shirt instead.

I have been researching this for a while, and have found it difficult to identify the wave functions/sinosoidal surfaces, or how to code them (my main language is R).

So. This isn't for a work project or anything. I am just wondering whether there is a kind soul in the SO community who would either know what the images were, or could suggest how to code them up? Or if they knew what the images were and therefore could point me in the right direction/resources and I'll figure out how to code it up!

Thanks in advance.

Edit: as per the comments, in my attempts to make this dream a reality, I got as far as searching 3D wireframe wave functions in terms of identifying what the images were. But, most resources pointed at Python. As I am a mere biologist who is predominantly an R user (with some bash and awk), the Python aspect seemed pretty daunting. So I guess half the battle is trying to figure out (roughly)  which specific wave forms the images are so I could search how to code them in R.

[image: T-shirt pattern]

Comment: Suggestion:  Type `3D wireframe wave functions`  or  `3D wireframe wave forms` into Google images and choose from the images that you get back.

Comment: See, I got as far as this. But I think where I came unstuck was that they were often in Python (which I haven't used before) and I wasn't sure how good a match the wave forms were... so that is partly why I was curious re: if anyone knew what these ones were, so that then I would know which specific wave forms I was looking up. Then could look for R specific resources for if I were coding it up.

Comment: I like this post! even though it is not on-topic here. You'd need to see what formats the T-shirt printing company would accept. Ideally they would take vector images, such as SVG. I expect a 3D plot could be converted to SVG. (You could use bitmaps, such as PNG, but they would have to be very high res in order not to lose any quality when printed).

Comment: Reddit would be fine to ask for ideas, as it is not curated in the way that Stack Overflow is. I have just done a bit of searching, and [found this](https://octave.org/doc/v4.2.1/Three_002dDimensional-Plots.html), which appears to be rendered by free software. Could you try that and see if it has a vector export feature?

Comment: @halfer I will check and find out, thank you so much for having a look! I will report back if I succeed.

Comment: No problem. It might be worth getting in touch with a T-shirt printing company in your area to see what image formats they support. They may require a bitmap (e.g. PNG), which may affect your choice of rendering software. That said, vector graphics can nearly always be converted to a bitmap (of whatever DPI resolution).